# How to find out if Windows installer is busy or not using delphi?

Tags: delphi, command-line, windows-installer

I have a Windows service that restarts windows in specific events but i have a problem with it. I don't want to restart windows when it is installing programs using windows installer.

So how i can fine out whether Windows installer is busy installing something or not.

any Delphi or Command line Function is acceptable.

Will you please help me ?

I found these 2 classess but I don't know how to use them.

[Class1](http://mfpack-media-foundation.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/MFPACK/JEDI/WinError.pas)  [class2](https://github.com/graemeg/freepascal/blob/master/packages/winunits-jedi/src/jwamsi.pas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [`this article`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/11/09/487559.aspx), which is quite outdated I've tried to implement both suggested options. The second one worked for me on Windows 7 SP1. The principle is to query the `MSIServer` service status and check, if this service is running and that accepts the [`SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP) control code. Here's a function wrapper for that:

```
uses
  WinSvc;

function IsWindowsInstallerBusy: Boolean;
var
  Service: SC_HANDLE;
  ServiceMgr: SC_HANDLE;
  ServiceStatus: SERVICE_STATUS;
begin
  Result := False;

  ServiceMgr := OpenSCManager(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if ServiceMgr <> 0 then
  try
    Service := OpenService(ServiceMgr, 'MSIServer', SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    if Service <> 0 then
    try
      if QueryServiceStatus(Service, ServiceStatus) then
      begin
        Result := (ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING) and
          ((ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted and SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP) = 0);
      end
      else
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot query service status. Code: %d',
          [GetLastError]);
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(Service);
    end
    else
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot open service. Code: %d',
        [GetLastError]);
  finally
    CloseServiceHandle(ServiceMgr);
  end
  else
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot connect to the service control ' +
      'manager. Code: %d', [GetLastError]);
end;
```

Comment: Though the article is outdated, it's still the most reliable source I'd say. It's written by the Windows Installer Team.

Comment: In the comments on that article is a gem from Heath Stewart saying to continue using the mutex.  Heath knows his stuff.

Comment: @Christopher, ah, thanks for the downvote! Just try to check if the `_MSIExecute` mutex is created by yourself...

Comment: It wasn't personal, you fell prey to misinformation from the MSI team.

Comment: @Zeid, could you accept the other answer here, please ?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Installer provides a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to tell you if an installation is in process.  I would use this over the SCManager API calls because it is thread safe.  Heath Stewart (MSFT MSI Expert) wrote about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/01/23/516454.aspx) and his advice should be given higher credibility then that of the Windows Installer team.

Comment: Well, have you tried that technique ? The only mutex I can see created by the msiexec.exe process is the `\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\MSCTF.Asm.MutexDefault1` in Process Explorer. So even when it might be more credible, it is still 8 years old article and many might have changed since that time. The documentation for MSI is catastrophic. [Windows 7 SP1]

Comment: I've been doing installers for 17 years and Windows Installer for 11 years.  For better or for worse, MSI hasn't changed in years. They've added a little here and there but they are very very much into backwards compatibility and are slow to change.  The mutex is valid and gets created when an MSI is in it's execute sequence.  The UI sequence doesn't create a mutex because the client side doesn't do installation.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm just guessing here because you did not provide enough information...**

(Some details about the goal and circumstances would have been nice.)

---

**1)** If you wish to restart the windows only when a specific installer is not running, you should enumerate running processes and if you find the installer you want to be aware of simply don't restart your system.

**2)** If you wish for a more generalised solution you still have a choice: The .msi typed installers are using **msiexec.exe**. If you wish to be aware of an installer of this type, you can search the list of the running processes for that.

---

Resources:

- About process enumeration read the [MSDN documentation on the topic.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- About doing it from delphi [read this tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/72604-getting-running-processes-list/)

Comment: Problem with Enumeration is this: When MSI packages does not start installing msiexec.exe in not running but when installation is finished msiexec.exe is still running therefor Enumeration won't help with that.

Comment: Well, this depends on your definition of "it [windows] is installing programs using windows installer". I think while msiexec.exe is not started, the installation is not started. Anyway TLama's answer is more correct than mine.